# How to keep the button size while changing the text?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a toggle button whose text has to change at each click:

```
<Button onClick={this.changeView}>{currentView === 'a' ? 'First' : 'Second Chance'}
                </Button>

changeView = (event, data) => {
    let nextView = (this.state.currentView === 'a') ? 'b' : 'a';
    this.setState({ currentView: nextView });
}
```

It works, but as the second label is way bigger than the first one the button keeps resizing. 
I'd like it to stay at a fixed length which would be the size of the second label...is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with `css` and `width` property.

Answer (score 0):

Set a width property to the Button.

2 options: inline style or css className. I would recommend the className option.

Inline style option:

```
<Button style={{width: '<YOUR_WIDTH>px'}} onClick={this.changeView}>{currentView === 'a' ? 'First' : 'Second Chance'}
                </Button>

changeView = (event, data) => {
    let nextView = (this.state.currentView === 'a') ? 'b' : 'a';
    this.setState({ currentView: nextView });
}
```